# Regex for uppercase Unicode does not match "Ó"?

Tags: regex, perl, unicode, utf-8

It seems that it does not recognize the accented Ó as uppercase

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.14.0;
use utf8;
use feature 'unicode_strings';

" SIMÓN " =~ /^\s+(\p{Upper}+)/u;
print "$1\n";
```

returns

```
SIM
```

Perl should be able to use Unicode data, which already tags Ó as uppercase.
From emacs `describe-char`

```
character code properties: customize what to show
  name: LATIN CAPITAL LETTER O WITH ACUTE
  old-name: LATIN CAPITAL LETTER O ACUTE
  general-category: Lu (Letter, Uppercase)
  decomposition: (79 769) ('O' '́')
```

Comment: I don't see how you could get a _more_ minimal case than what's provided :-)

Comment: Ah, my apologies, @pst. I was only really looking at line _count_ rather than content. You're correct that the RE itself could probably be simplified.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're missing `use open ':std', ':locale';` to properly encode your output.

If that doesn't work, your file isn't encoded using UTF-8 even though you tell Perl it is.

Comment: That worked! I do not understand at all, since I my example only uses a string and not a file... I guess something is borked when I do the `print $1`

Comment: Exactly. `:std` causes strings sent to STDOUT and STDERR to be encoded, and bytes from STDIN to be decoded.