# Regex for matching accent characters

Tags: regex, string, perl

**Aim:**
I want to separate words to count their frequency in a document and then do some calculations on those frequencies.

The words can begin/contain/end with any of the following:

- numbers
- alphabets (including é, ú, ó etc but not symbols like $,#,& etc)

The words can contain (but not begin or end with)

- underscore (eg: rishi_dua)
- single quote (eg: can't)
- hyphen (eg: 123-)

The words can be separated by any symbol or whitespace like $, #, &, tab character

**Problem:**

1. I'm not able to find out how to match é, ú, ó etc without matching
   other special characters.
2. What would be a more efficient way to do this (*optional*)
3. Splitting by space is working for me at the moment as there is no other

**What I've tried:**

**Approach:**
First I replace everything except \w  (alphanumeric plus "_"), ' and - with a space
Then I remove ', _ and ' if it is found at the beginning or end of a word
Finally I replace multiple spaces with single space and split the words

**Code:**
I am using a series of regex replace as follows:

```
$str =~ s/[^\w'-]/ /g;
#Also tried using $str =~ s/[^:alpha:0-9_'-]/ /g; but doesn't work
$str =~ s/- / /;
$str =~ s/' / /;
$str =~ s/_ / /;
$str =~ s/ -/ /;
$str =~ s/ '/ /;
$str =~ s/ _/ /;

$str =~ s/ +/ /;
foreach $word (split(' ', lc $str)) {
    #do something
}
```

**Constraints:**
I have to do it in Perl (since this is a part of a larger code I've writen in Perl) but I can use other options apart from Regex

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use the `\p{L}` character class that matches all letters. and use `\P{L}` that matches all that is not a letter.

To allow quote and hyphen you can use :

`\p{L}[\p{L}'_-]*` or `\p{L}+(?:['_-]\p{L}+)*` to avoid non-letters at the bounds.

Notice: some accented characters are figured with several code points, for instance, even if a code point exists for `à` (a grave), it can also be made with two code points: the ascii letter `a` and the combining character ` (grave accent). `\p{L}\p{Mn}*` can match these kind of glyphs:

```
(?>\p{L}\p{Mn}*)+(?:['_-](?>\p{L}\p{Mn}*)+)*
```

---

Using a split method is more hazardous and difficult IMO, in particular if you want to deal with combining characters. But basically to match the separators you can use :

`[^\p{L}\p{Mn}'_-]+`

Or to be more explicit:

`[^\p{L}\p{Mn}'_-]+|(?<![\p{L}\p{Mn}])['_-]+|[-_']+(?!\p{L})` that split on hyphens and quotes that are not surrounded by letters.

Comment: @Rishi also take a look at the perl unicode extensions: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlunicode.html

Comment: @Casimir, I just tried your code. It's not working for me. As suggested by Eli Algranti and Jim Monty, I guess it's got something to do with character encoding. I'll read it up

Comment: @RishiDua: take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10891643/regex-for-uppercase-unicode-does-not-match

Comment: @ikegami, I'm not sure if I understood your question correctly.
I didn't specify anything for the decoding (I guess it's whatever the default decoding is). I read the file using
open (INFILE, 'input.txt');
while(<INFILE>) {
followed by the code in the question

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte, Thanks! I'm a newbie at character encoding. I will read it once I've finished reading up the basics of character encoding.

Comment: There is no automatic decoding, so "default encoding" makes no sense. You're matching against bytes when you're expected to provide Unicode code points (decoded text).

Answer (score 2):

Read [Tom Christiansen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/471272/tchrist)'s extraordinarily detailed answer to [Why does modern Perl avoid UTF-8 by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6162484/why-does-modern-perl-avoid-utf-8-by-default/6163129#6163129). The short answer to your question is that you must ensure you're decoding and encoding the text properly, and you must understand how to use Perl regular expression patterns to match Unicode text.

Comment: Thanks! I just noticed that the perl file I'm using for testing and the actual data file that I'm using are opened using different encoding in Notepad++. I'm a newbie to encoding. Will read that stuff up. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You may find this cpan module interesting. I have used it before and it worked well for me.  It can be used to simply remove the accents from characters:

http://search.cpan.org/~pjacklam/Text-Unaccent-PurePerl-0.05/lib/Text/Unaccent/PurePerl.pm