# Perl regex replacement of logical unicode characters

Tags: perl, unicode

Here is a simple substitution that adds parentheses arounds upper-case characters in an unicode string. As you can see, the result is rather ugly:

```
~$ echo "Whatéver 5" | perl -ape "s/(\p{Upper})/(\1)/g"
(W)hat(�)�ver 5
```

My understanding is that the regex operates on "code points" instead of "logical characters", which splits my 'é' into meaningless characters. Is there a way to force the regex to work on logical unicode characters at once ?

Thanks,

Comment: There are som missing the UTF8 PerlIO layers on input and output. The following works as expected: `echo -n "Whatéver 5" | perl -Mutf8 -CSDA -pe "s/(\p{Upper})/(\1)/g"`. See also [Regex for uppercase Unicode does not match “Ó”?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10891643/regex-for-uppercase-unicode-does-not-match-%C3%93)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your terminal uses UTF-8 encoding,

```
$ echo -n "é" | perl -ne 'printf "%vX\n", $_'
```

gives

```
C3.A9
```

so the input to the Perl program has not been converted internally to Unicode (it is still a string of UTF-8 bytes)

To convert the input to a Perl string, add a UTF-8 layer on the standard input stream using option `-CI` :

```
$ echo -n "é" | perl -CI -ne 'printf "%vX\n", $_'
```

the output is now

```
E9
```

However, if you also try to print the character back to standard output
you will not get `é` but a unicode replacement character `�` from the terminal. This is because the character `0xE9` is Unicode, but the terminal expect UTF-8, and `0xE9` is not valid UTF-8:

```
$ echo -n "é" | perl -CI -nE 'printf "$_: %vX\n", $_, $_'
�: E9
```

To get correct output, you can add an UFT-8 encoding layer on the standard output stream also (using `-CO` flag):

```
$ echo -n "é" | perl -CIO -nE 'printf "$_: %vX\n", $_, $_'
é: E9
```

According to [perlunicode](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrecharclass.html)

> "Upper" is a synonym for "Uppercase" , and we could have written
>   \p{Uppercase} equivalently as \p{Upper}

and

> For instance, \p{Uppercase} matches any single character with the
>   Unicode "Uppercase" property

It seems like if you try to use `\p{Upper}` on a byte string, you will not get any warnings from Perl. Also bytes in the range `0xC0` to `0xDE` will match the uppercase property. Try

```
perl -E 'for $i (0x80..0xFF) {$_=chr $i; printf "%x\n", $i if /\p{Upper}/}'
```

This explains the output you got:

```
$ echo "Whatéver 5" | perl -ape "s/(\p{Upper})/(\1)/g"
(W)hat(�)�ver 5
```

Here, the letter `é` is represented as 2 bytes (in UTF-8) `0xC3` and `0xA9`, and `0xC3` will match the Unicode `Upper` property.

A solution to your problem is therefore to add UTF-8 encoding layers on the standard input and output (you can combine `-CI` and `-CO` using `-CS`):

```
echo "Whatéver 5" | perl -CS -ape "s/(\p{Upper})/(\1)/g"
```

with output:

```
(W)hatéver 5
```

Answer (score 4):

As illustrated by the other answers, turning on UTF-8 in Perl is a piecemeal process. There's `use utf8` for the syntax and raw strings. Then you have to make sure all your filehandles are UTF-8. What about `@ARGV`? `readdir`? `glob`? The output from ``` `` ```?

There's nothing worse than having half your program working in ASCII and the other half working in UTF-8. [utf8::all](https://metacpan.org/pod/utf8::all) to the rescue!

Install it, add `use utf8::all`, and it will turn on UTF-8... all of it. Someone else figured it out, you don't have to worry about it.

```
$ echo "Whatéver 5" | perl -ape "use utf8::all; s/(\p{Upper})/(\1)/g"
(W)hatéver 5
```

Answer (score 2):

You haven't told Perl to expect UTF-8 input, so it is treating each byte of the encoding as a separate character

Within a program you can set the default encoding for the three standard IO channels like this

```
use open ':std' => ':encoding(UTF-8)'
```

On the command line, the option `-CS` does the same thing, so this should work for you. I have removed the unnecessary autosplit option and replaced `\1` with the correct `$1` in the replacement string

```
echo "Whatéver 5" | perl -CS -pe "s/(\p{Upper})/($1)/g"
```