# Perl regex groups do not display unicode characters correctly

Tags: regex, perl, unicode

If I use the following code, the regex group does not show the expected unicode string. Can somebody explain to me whether I did a mistake, or is it even possible that it is an intrinsic problem in perl itself.

```
echo 'éá'|perl -ne 'if ( /(\P{L}+)/ ) { print $1; }'
�
```

Even if I take this [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39295880/perl-regex-replacement-of-logical-unicode-characters) into account and add the UTF-8 encoding layers to perl, it still does not give me the string 'éá' for the regex group:

```
echo 'éá'|perl -CS -ne 'if ( /(\P{L}+)/ ) { print $1,$_; }'

éá
```

The output for the group seems to be empty and includes a newline sign.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Use `/(\p{L}+)/`, you used the opposite regex.

Comment: What @WiktorStribiżew is saying is that `\P` with a capital `P` means _not one of these_, while `\p` with a small `p` is _one of these_.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick replies.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow and the Perl tag by the way. Very well-worded first question. :)

Comment: You can do code-highlighting in comments with backticks `\`foo\``. I don't see a difference to the code in the question.

Comment: @WiktorStribizew and simbaque, you guys are right. My mistake ;-) Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your input, `éá` are 2 Unicode letters. `\P{L}` is a construct matching any character *other than* a Unicode letter.

So, using the opposite construct - `\p{L}` - you will fix your issue.

Use

```
/(\p{L}+)/
```